# How to make Radio Buttons mutually exclusive of Entire Row in a table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have one requirement in my Web application, hope I will get help here..

```
<div id="Content">
<table id="Grid1">
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="test1"></td><td>One</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="test2"></td><td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="test3"></td><td>Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

These Radio Buttons should mutually exclusive. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're asking, you have to use several forms, for this instance, 3 forms.

```
<form> 
    <input type="radio" name="choice1a" value="1a">Choice 1a
    <input type="radio" name="choice1b" value="1b">Choice 1b
</form>
<form> 
    <input type="radio" name="choice2a" value="2a">Choice 2a
</form>
<form> 
    <input type="radio" name="choice3a" value="3a">Choice 3a
</form>
```